# Concatenate String to unicode in java

Tags: java, unicode, concatenation

```
public class TruthTableValue {
    private boolean truthValue;
    private String name = "";

    private int unicodeStartNameValue = 41; /*
    * we want our String always to start with A and then go up the alphabet.
    * this can be done using the unicode 16.
    */

    public TruthTableValue() {
        truthValue = true;
        name += "\u00" + Character.toString((char)unicodeStartNameValue);
        unicodeStartNameValue++;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

In this code I try to have an object which creates after every generation an object with a name which is equal to the unicode "\u00" + "41" or "42" or "43" and so on (A, B, C and so on).
My problem is that "\u00" is in accordance with the compiler not a "valid unicode", so that it doesn't compile properly and it's not possible to execute it neither.

How do I get rid of the compile error or how do I solve this problem in general?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What should getName() return? This code has a boolean that isn't used anywhere, an integer that is incremented in the constructor but is never used anywhere, and a name initialized with something that doesn't compile. What are you trying to achieve? To concatenate a String with the char 0x41, all you need is `s += (char) 0x41;`

Comment: Remove `"\u00" +`.

Comment: unicode for an upper case A is \u0041. After one object is generated (in another class) the unicodeStartNameValue is incremented and \u00 should be concatenated with 42 which would result to a name of B for my second object. To get this name I created the getter getName() which returns the name String which is a unicode

Comment: No. Unicode for A if 0x41, or 65, in decimal. You can use the \u0041 unicode character escape sequence inside a String or char **literal** to represent that character. But it still represents a single character. Concatenating "\u00" with 41 doesn't make sense, because \u00 is not a valid unicode character escape sequence. unicode escape sequences are useful for characters that are not printable, or can't be typed easily with a keyboard. But in your case, you can just use `char start = 'A';` to initialize your character, and `start++` to increment it.

Comment: `char start = 'A';` is equivalent to `char start = 0x41;`, which is equivalent to `char start = 65;`, which is equivalent to `char start = '\u0041';`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"\u0041"` in a Java program is processed by the *compiler*, not at run time.  If the Java compiler sees this in a program, it will treat it as the string `"A"`.  (That's why you're getting an error; the compiler doesn't know what to do if `\u` isn't followed by four hex digits.)

If you want something that converts the 6-character string `"\\u0041"` to `"A"` at **run time**, you'll need to find a library method for that.  I don't know of one, and it's the hard way to do it anyway.  In Java, a `char` is already a number.  So if you say

```
private char unicodeStartNameValue = 0x41;
```

instead of

```
private int unicodeStartNameValue = 41;
```

and keep adding 1 to the `char`, you'll have the characters you want, and you can convert them to strings with `Character.toString(charValue)`, which would return a 1-character string.  (If you just say `41`, that's a decimal number, and first character would be `')'`, not `'A'`.)

Your idea wouldn't work, anyway, because you wouldn't be able to get `"\u004a"`.  If you were keeping a decimal number and trying to append it to `"\u00"`, your sequence would be A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, P, Q, R, ..., since it would jump from `"\u0049"` to `"\u0050"`.